# how to get the top 10 countries based on no. of occurence in excel column

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet like this

```
       _____________________________________________________
       |        A             B               C     |   D   |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |      Device   |    Country    |            |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  2   |      Android  |     iNDIA     |            |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  3   |      aNDROID  |     India     |            |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  4   |      Android  |   Bangladesh  |            |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  5   |      Android  |    Pakistan   |            |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

Now I India has two occurence, Pakistan has 1 occurence and Banglasdesh too has one ocuerence

I just want is that the top 10 countries(based on their occuerences) will be listed along with their occuerneces

C will have top 10 countries and D will have no. of their ocurences.

How can i acheive that

EDIT: I am very weak at excel sheet, any idea will be helpfull. I know how to write formula in the formula bar, just tell me what formula shall i write

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables are extremely useful in your circumstance. Put **Country** into Row field and **Country** again into Values field - you can sort by largest to smallest